# Commands out of sync MySQL when calling for the second time a stored procedure in C

Tags: mysql, c, database, synchronization, connector

I created a Database using mySQL, and now i need to launch the stored procedures i created, programming a basic C client, which asks for a command, and call the stored procedures.

In particular, after the login, while i don't input '10' to logout my program asks for which SP i want to call. That's my code:

```
void root_logged ()
    {
        while (true)
        {   
            scanf ("%i",&cmd2);
            if (cmd2 == 2)
            {
                show_exams();
            }
            else if (cmd2 == 10)
            {
                do_logout();
                break;
            }
        }
    }


void show_exams ()
{
    strcpy(query,"call show_exams()"); //call mySQL SP
    mysql_query (conn,query);
    result = mysql_store_result(conn);

    if (result == NULL)
    {
        finish_with_error(conn, "errore");
    }

    printf ("check 2:\n");
    num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    printf ("check 3 \n");
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
        {   
            if (i == 0) 
            {              
                while(field = mysql_fetch_field(result))
                {
                    printf( "|  %s  ", field->name);
                }
                printf("\n");           
            }
            printf(" %s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL"); 
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
    mysql_free_result(result);
}
```

If i enter '2' for the first time after the login it correctly show me the entire table 'exams', with all the data stored in.

After the result, the program asks for another command. If i enter again 2 (or any other cmd except 10 to logout), it gives me this error.

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Any idea? I think the problem it's `about mysql_store_result()` and `mysql_free_result()` not used properly

Comment: Which part of your code produces this error message?

Comment: `result = mysql_store_result(conn)`, when i call the procedure for the second time. This because the if statement below check `if result == NULL` return the error code occurred during `mysql_store_result(result)`. So i think i have a problem using `mysql_free_result()`